# Android launcher keeps crashing after i install my app

Tags: android, launcher

I am an experienced android developer but recently I have been developing an app and whenever I install it on any device, the device's launcher keeps crashing. Once the launcher starts crashing it keeps on doing so and is forced to reset the whole device to factory settings. 
I have never experienced this issue before and I am currently only testing using emulators yet the same problem is persistent. From my logs, I can see the launcher app is throwing a memory exception.

```
Process: com.android.launcher3, PID: 2645
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 400160028-byte allocation with 3740058 free bytes and 90MB until OOM
```

I don't know how to resolve this since it's not my app that is crashing but rather the launchers. What I am sure of is that my app is what is causing the crashes. Any insight will really help.

Comment: How big is your launcher icon? If it's a massive bitmap, it could conceivably cause the launcher to OOM.

Comment: that is definitely Android launcher's problem, not yourth

Comment: @ditn you are right. Have changed the icon now it's running smoothly. Have no idea why i didn't think of that. Thank you.